# Array Indexing. printing elements of the middle column

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

**hackerank array indexing**
The Problem description is as follows
Write the function array_index which accepts three numbers n,n_row,n_col and performs the array operations given below

1. Create a array x of shape(n_row,n_col), having first n natural numbers.
   2.Print elements of last row
2. Print elements of middle column.
   4.Print elements, overlapping first two rows and last three columns
   ***My python code is as follows***

---

```
import numpy as np
def array_index(n, n_row, n_col):
    
        x = np.arange(n).reshape(n_row, n_col)
        print(x[n_col])
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        
        n = int(input())
        n_row = int(input())
        n_col = int(input())
        array_index(n, n_row, n_col)
```

Can someone help me complete the solution for this problem
PS: Attached the image of the question for the reference[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRo3p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(n).reshape(n_row,n_col)
print(x[-1])
y=int(n_col/2)
print(x[:,y])
print(x[0:2,-3:])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.